# what kind of factory pattern to implement when methods accept different signatures?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, oop

**How do I define a factory whose implementations may accept different numbers of parameters?**

```
public abstract class CarFactory
{
    public abstract void countStuff(??); //not sure how to define this
}
```

I would like the factory to be able to create different objects like:

```
public class BMW : CarFactory
{
  public override void countStuff(param1, param2) {}
}

public class Ford : CarFactory
{
    public override void countStuff(param1) {}
}
```

Comment: CarFactory<T> where T:Tuple, countStuff(T args), BMW : CarFactory<Tuple<string, int>> etc etc

Comment: To elucidate on my above comment you can use Tuples and Generics to provide this in some circumstances

Comment: in that case it would seem that im using the wrong pattern? should i not be using factory?

Comment: though actually it now occurs to me we've done this using a slightly odd internal tuple the .net one and the where clause wont work with the normal .net tuple, though the pattern will

Comment: Well in depends on why the number of params is varying,  at the moment T is an 'in T' and so if it collapses away on construction the pattern seems okay

Comment: If the parameters all have the same type you can just have an indefinite number of them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229008(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Milosz has given a full answer outlining the type of thign I mean but with custom classes, its the same basic pattern.

Comment: Note that you can't `override` a member _and_ change its parameters.  You _could_ have different overloads in the base class and override each of them, but then it's not clear _which_ override should be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if "countStuff" should be a factory responsibility, but you could get something similar this way:

```
public interface ICountParam {}

public class BmwParam : ICountParam
{
    public BmwParam(string a)
    {
        A = a;
    }

    public string A { get; set; }
}
public class FordParam : ICountParam
{
    public FordParam(string a, string b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public interface ICarFactory<in T> where T : ICountParam
{
    void CountStuff(T param);
}

public class BMW : ICarFactory<BmwParam>
{
    public void CountStuff(BmwParam param) { }
}

public class Ford : ICarFactory<FordParam>
{
    public void CountStuff(FordParam param) { }
}
```

Usage:

```
 bmw.CountStuff(new BmwParam("A"));
 ford.CountStuff(new FordParam("A", "B"));
```